# How to show a LaTeX command in lstlisting?

Tags: listings

I code this in a .tex file.

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}
  % This is the syntax for inserting code.
  \begin{lstlisting}
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
```

And this is what I expect:

```latex
  % This is the syntax for inserting code.
  \begin{lstlisting}
  \end{lstlisting}
```

Unfortunately, this is not feasible. What is the correct format?

Comment: The question is clear. I don't see why it has been closed. It might be a duplicate, but I couldn't find it. Anyway, the solution is to do `\lstnewenvironment{LSTLISTING}{}{}` in the document preamble and use `\begin{LSTLISTING}...\end{LSTLISTING}` in order to show the usage of `lstlisting`.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE...

Is the below match with your requirement:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
  % This is the syntax for inserting code.
  \begin{lstlisting}
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```